# Strange behavior boost::async_write with Serial_Port

Tags: serial-port, boost-asio

I`m trying to implement sync write with timeout. i use deadline timer and async_write

Code:

```
size_t SerialBus::timeout_write(std::vector<byte>& buf)
{
    isWriteTimeOut_=false;
    bytes_writen_=0;

    // After a timeout & cancel it seems we need
    // to do a reset for subsequent reads to work.
    port_.get_io_service().reset();

    // Asynchronously read 1 character.
    boost::asio::async_write(port_, boost::asio::buffer(buf), 
        boost::bind(&PLT::SerialBus::write_complete, 
        this, 
        boost::asio::placeholders::error, 
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred)); 

    // Setup a deadline time to implement our timeout.
    timerWrite_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(timeout_));
    timerWrite_.async_wait(boost::bind(&PLT::SerialBus::timeOutWriteHandler,
        this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

    port_.get_io_service().run();

    return bytes_writen_;
}

void SerialBus::timeOutWriteHandler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    // Was the timeout was cancelled?
    if (error) {
        // yes
        isWriteTimeOut_=false;
        return;
    }
    // no, we have timed out, so kill
    // the read operation
    // The read callback will be called
    // with an error
    isWriteTimeOut_=true;       
    port_.cancel();
}

void SerialBus::write_complete(const boost::system::error_code& error,
    size_t bytes_transferred) 
{
    bytes_writen_=bytes_transferred;
    errorCode_=error;
    timerWrite_.cancel();
}
```

i have the same read functions

When i use timeout_write with long enough buffer and timer expires. when this happend async_write handler write_complete get 995 error, bytes_transfered is 0, buf become empty(in fact it is member of the same class and it life time long enough) but data is transfered. when i call timeout_read i get the right answers from my device (FTDI). when buffer length less and write complete called before timer everything is Ok (bufer had exatcly what i put in it). . when i used synced version of write it block COM until i restart it with usb cable replug.

In that case i don`t know how to determine what was really send to device or correct cancel transmition. Or i need to use native functions instead boost?

I use boost 1.58 Win7 x64 and ftdi 2.12.00 and vs2010

Comment: And i don`t understand why the sync version blocked the port until it unplug and not send all data but async not just canceled by timer and send piece of data but transfered all data

Comment: Error 995 is ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED, "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request".  Well, that's what you wanted, you got it.  Setting the timeout too low is a pretty common mistake, there's no upper bound on how long the device can turn off the handshake.  Only use it to detect gross device failure, don't go below 10 seconds.

Comment: Boost.Asio's serial port support is a very thin wrapper, so native functions may yield the same results.  From my experience, the root problem is often that the virtual COM port driver fails to behave exactly as if it was a true COM port.

Comment: Yes i understand this error is invoked by timeout, and maybe it was just  problem of diagnostic. but if async version didn`t broke port like sync version and if i understand sources of asio right difference between functions that is async uses multiple winApi::writeFile() but if so, why it impossible to return already transfered byteWritten? Anyway winApi::PurgeComm solve my problem. And yes it look it is driver problem with sync version.